# Bootstrap menu item disappears when toggled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

One of my menu item disappears in mobile view when menu button is clicked.

Here is the website I'm doing

http://rrphotography.net/

Any help or solutions to this would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your menu item is showing but it disappears. We can't tell anything without looking at code. You should add code, how you are toggling menu in your question.

Comment: Hi Saqib I'm using bootstrap toggle to toggle the menus

Comment: Can you edit your question and add code?